# Is there anyway to delete my users cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, browser-cache, service-worker-events

I made a sw.js file that caches my chat website so users can open in offline mode, however, the Service Worker file caused alot of issues including not being able to see new messages and alot of website crashes so I was forced to delete it. Sadly my none of my current users can delete the cache manually! NOte that I kept the sw.js file but it's now empty so is there any code I can write to delete all of my current user caches?

I don't think this is relevant but my app uses django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the cache, you can use inbuild cache API.

```
caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
    cacheNames.forEach(value => {
        caches.delete(value);
    });
})
```

Removing content from your sw.js file is not enough. If there is already a service worker installed and running then I would suggest you to "unRegister" that also.  You can do so
programmatically using below code.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
    for(let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister()
    } 
})
```

Please note you only need to run this code once in all the user's browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, should i place this code in the base HTML file or in the empty sw.js file? also is there anyway to check if the code already ran in user's browser to it doesn't run again? thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You can place this code in Base HTML file but there might be an issue, as if that HTML file is served from the cached then these changes will not reflect and executed.

Comment: I doubt that if there is a way to know ahead if this code is executed or not. There are some other way to tackle this situation. For e.g. let it run for current release and after few weeks in new release remove this piece of code as it no longer required, Till then everyone cache would be cleared.